# Values pf pandas data frame columns as list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am creating a data frame from dictionary in a list like below :

```
[{'points': [-9.3613566605198262, 4.0910018605047171, -9.3473134841172731, 4.0960021770649475], 'uid': 0},
 {'points': [-9.4687215264026712, 4.0132947848279499, -9.3641925245477857, 4.0159059337303784], 'uid': 1},
```

The above is a list called l1

For data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l1)
```

This creates following df:

```
   points                                          uid                                
0  [-9.3613566605198262, 4.09100186050......]      0
1  [-9.4687215264026712, 4.01329478482......]      1
```

I want to know how to remove the list format/ square brackets from the points column, and it should contain simple comma separated values.

Also, How to limit the decimal place only to 2 digits?

I tried the following, but it doesn't works.

```
np.round(df, 2)
```

and

```
df.round({'points':2})
```

expected df

```
   points                      uid
0  -9.36, 4.09, -9.34, 4.09    0
1  -9.46, 4.01, -9.36, 4.01    1
```

Comment: if you don't want the list format, what's your expectation?

Comment: update the question @Tiny.D

Comment: @Liza you don't heed `from_records`, you can just use the default DataFrame creator as `pd.DataFrame(l1)`

Comment: yes, thats true, I have tried that, but it shows me as a list and not df even after doing pd.DataFrame(l1), I couldn't perform any df operation on it, so I went with from_records()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use apply to round the numbers in the list and then concat as a string.

```
df['points'] = df.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(str(round(e,2)) for e in x.points),axis=1)

df
Out[1042]: 
                     points  uid
0   -9.36, 4.09, -9.35, 4.1    0
1  -9.47, 4.01, -9.36, 4.02    1
```

Comment: you don't need to use `apply(..., axis=1)` here, it would clearer IMO to use `df.points.map`

Comment: also you don't need the square brackets inside `join`, you can leave it as a generator comprehension, i.e. `join(round(e,2) for in x)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(l1)
df['points'] = [', '.join(str(e) for e in [round(i, 2) for i in j]) 
                                 for j in df['points']]
df
```

df will be:

```
    points                  uid
0   -9.36, 4.09, -9.35, 4.1 0
1   -9.47, 4.01, -9.36, 4.02    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up... you don't need `from_records`, `pd.DataFrame` handles lists of dictionaries just fine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(l1)
df

                                                                           points  uid
0  [-9.361356660519826, 4.091001860504717, -9.347313484117272, 4.096002177064947]    0
1   [-9.468721526402671, 4.01329478482795, -9.364192524547786, 4.015905933730378]    1
```

I like using these string formatters instead

```
f = lambda n: ', '.join(['{:.2f}'] * n).format
d = lambda x: f(len(x))(*x)
df.assign(points=df.points.apply(d))

                     points  uid
0  -9.36, 4.09, -9.35, 4.10    0
1  -9.47, 4.01, -9.36, 4.02    1
```

Comment: Using join() changes the data type as its a python string method, is there another way to attain the above without changing the data type? @piRSquared

Comment: @Liza you want a comma separated string?  Or a list object?  If string, then the fact I'm converting to string within `{:.2f}` should not matter.

Comment: I have to further use these values in a function, so I dont want it to be as string, neither should it be in square brackets, simply float values with commas, is it possible?

Comment: Or if I can change the list to a tuple, that will work too

Comment: @Liza those brackets merely indicate that it is a list. If you insist on floats then you must maintain an array structure. Everyone thought you wanted a string because you stated that you didn't want those brackets. If I'm to help any further, you'll need to be more explicit about what you want. Otherwise I'm wasting my time guessing.